# Python Dict to JSON: json.dumps unicode error, but ord(str(dict)) yields nothing over 128

Tags: python, json, dictionary, unicode, ord

I have a task where I needed to generate a portable version of a data dictionary, with some extra fields inserted.  I ended up building a somewhat large Python dictionary, which I then wanted to convert to JSON.  However, when I attempt this conversion...

```
with open('CPS14_data_dict.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(data_dict,f,indent=4,encoding='utf-8')
```

I get smacked with an exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 17: invalid start byte
```

I know this is a common error, but I cannot, for the life of me, find an instance of how one locates the problematic portion in the dictionary.  The only plausible thing I have seen is to convert the dictionary to a string and run `ord()` on each character:

```
for i,c in enumerate(str(data_dict)):
    if ord(c)>128:
        print i,'|',c
```

The problem is, this operation returns nothing at all.  Am I missing something about how `ord()` works?  Alternatively, a position (17) is reported, but it's not clear to me what this refers to.  There do not appear to be any problems at the 17th character, row, or entry.

I should say that I know about the `ensure_ascii=False` option.  Indeed, it will write to disk (and it's beautiful).  This approach, however, seems to just kick the can down the road.  I get the same encoding error when I try to read the file back in.  Since I will want to use this file for multiple purposes (converted back to a dictionary), this is an issue.

It would also be helpful to note that this is my work computer with Windows 7, so I don't have my shell tools to explore the file (and my VM is on the fritz).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `str(data_dict)` produces a represtation using only ASCII characters, always. Non-ASCII bytes in bytestrings will be represented using `\xhh` character sequences.

Comment: Dang.  Is `\xhh` the actual sequence that is used every time?  Or is it just an example?  Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html may make a good read...

Comment: @MarvinWardJr: Any byte over 127 will be represented using that sequence; Python reflects the value as a [string literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: \x92 is an apostrophe in case you were trying to look for it manually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you want to claim the answer?  You got me on the path to resolving the issue.  Ultimately, I just rolled through each line of the raw data and tried to encode to UTF-8.  When it didn't work, I took note of the sequence, and then I read the data in again replacing all of the "bad" sequences with spaces (the `ignore` option of `encode()` was not working for some reason).

Comment: @MarvinWardJr: if you actually showed us an object that reflects your situation and that would reproduce your issue, I could write you a real answer instead.

Comment: @MarvinWardJr: your dictionary has *bytestrings* that are not UTF-8 decodable, but we don't really know what kind of data you have. Is it text, or binary data like images? If it is text, do you know what codec would be correct for them, or have at least enough of the data and how you got it for us to help you figure that out?

Comment: I am not sure it makes sense to provide all of the code used to generate the dictionary, but here is a link to the raw data:  http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/cps/march/asec2014early_pubuse.dd.txt  It holds the problematic characters.  (If I were at home, I could just provide a link to the Notebook.  I don't, however, have git access here, and I don't want to spend to much time setting up another access point.)